# How to install Pandoc on ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, xmonad, cabal, pandoc

Does anyone have suggestions about how to install pandoc on Arch? I am trying to install pandoc-static from here: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pandoc-static/, although it appears to be conflicting with my xmonad installation (I use xmonad as a TWM):

```
[grease-lightning]/home/.../builds/pandoc-static$ makepkg -s
==> Making package: pandoc-static 1.15.0.6-1 (Sun Aug 16 23:18:48 PDT 2015)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Found pandoc-static-1.15.0.6-1.tar.xz
  -> Found pandoc-static-1.15.0.6-1.tar.xz.sig
==> Validating source files with sha512sums...
    pandoc-static-1.15.0.6-1.tar.xz ... Passed
    pandoc-static-1.15.0.6-1.tar.xz.sig ... Skipped
==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
    pandoc-static-1.15.0.6-1.tar.xz ... Passed
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Extracting pandoc-static-1.15.0.6-1.tar.xz with bsdtar
==> Starting prepare()...
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Starting build()...
  -> Skipping List-0.5.2
  -> Skipping SHA-1.6.4.2
  -> Skipping base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1
  -> Skipping byteable-0.1.1
  -> Skipping cereal-0.4.1.1
  -> Skipping cmdargs-0.10.13
  -> Building data-default-class-0.0.1
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' does not exist. Run 'cabal
update' to download it.
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
data-default-class-0.0.1 (reinstall)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
data-default-instances-old-locale-0.0.1
data-default-0.5.3
X11-1.6.1.2
xmonad-contrib-0.11.4
xmonad-0.11.1
X11-xft-0.3.1
data-default-instances-dlist-0.0.1
data-default-instances-containers-0.0.1
data-default-instances-base-0.0.1
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

I am afraid of breaking my xmonad TWM if I force the reinstall. What should I do?

Perhaps I should install Pandoc via `sudo cabal install --global pandoc`? If so, how should I install `cabal`? I was thinking that I should download it from here: https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html

Any suggestions or recommendations are appreciated. I am also happy to clarify anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, the AUR packages have been very broken for some time.  The easiest way to do it is just to install cabal-install and then install pandoc in your home directory with (as non-root):

```
cabal update
cabal install pandoc
```

Then you end up with pandoc in ~/.cabal/bin/pandoc.

It would be great if someone fixes the AUR packages, but until then, using cabal to install something in system risks making updates to ghc not work properly.

### clarification

When you use `cabal` to install stuff in your home directory, it puts files under `~/.ghc` and `~/.cabal`.  So worst case if you want to start fresh you can just recursively delete those directories.  By contrast, when you install stuff in `/usr` without pacman (as would happen with `cabal install --global ...`), there might be residue there that makes it hard to upgrade ghc.

Comment: When you say `using cabal to install something in system risks making updates to ghc not work properly`, are you referring to a "thorough" cabal install, and not the `cabal-install` tool? Thus, if I use the `cabal-install` tool to run `cabal install pandoc` (without `sudo`), then I am not risking a break in my xmonad installation, right? Just to be sure, `cabal-install` installs everything under my home directory, which makes the installation safer, right?

Comment: I am saying the `--global` flag to cabal install is dangerous because it will write stuff to `/usr` that is not under `pacman`'s control, but the `--user` flag should be fine because it only affects what is under `$HOME/.cabal`.  When you aren't root, things default to `--user`.

Answer (score 6):

The dynamic linked [`pandoc` package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/pandoc/) just entered [community] on Oct 13, 2015. For now the installation is huge, but we will try to improve.

Comment: Update: `pandoc` is not depending on the haskell libs any more, and you can install `haskell-pandoc` whenever you need the libraries.

Comment: just installed pandoc using pacman, it's saying can't find `libcmark.so.0.27.0` library. I checked, cmark is installed and is version 0.27

Comment: it appears that pandoc package is looking for cmark 0.27.0 but the latest version is 0.27.1. Please update the pandoc package

Comment: Your mirror may be out of date or your system may not be fully updated. I do not have the problem here.

Comment: i ran pacman -Syu prior to doing this. i should mention i'm running on armv7h architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following command：

```bash
Yay -Sy pandoc
```